# does output from LHS of pipe become an arg for RHS of pipe

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm having difficulty grasping how pipes work. Initially I thought of them as per the title but I couldn't get a simple example to work e.g.

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
echo "rubbish" > txtfile
ls | cat
```

I'm wondering why it returns the output from 'ls' rather than the output of 'cat txtfile' (i.e. "rubbish"). I've read many pipe tutorials but none of them seem to go beyond "STDOUT of LHS becomes STDIN for RHS" and I'm left wondering what is STDIN of RHS. Does it become the first argument? Where does it slot in when RHS of pipe has options or more than one argument. Is there any kind of macro substitution taking place or is my thinking wide of the mark.

Edit: I'm still none the wiser 5 comments later. I'll certainly take a look at Roadowl's pv utility but for now if I type

```
ls | cut -c 2-4
```

I get

```
xtf
```

which I'd expect. So, does cut take its input from stdin but cat doesn't?

Edit2: I stuck the question up on askubuntu (I originally put it up here by mistake). The answer there https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316848/does-output-from-lhs-of-pipe-become-an-arg-for-rhs-of-pipe throws a bit more light on it.

Edit3: While reading the answers here and ask ubuntu and the links therein it struck me (again) how woeful bash (& cohorts) are. It's almost like they're designed to trip you up. I only started using bash a couple of months back and every time I write a script I have to read endless web pages to get it to work or discover where I'm going wrong. Take a simple [[ $1=="..." ]] condition. You forget the spaces round the operator and the else condition might wipe some files you want without so much as a warning. Yes, you can do great things with it without a lot of typing but at times it's like using a tightrope to get from skyscraper A to skyscraper B to avoid using 2 lifts. What's up with gold c code like cat(ls())? That said, thanks to everyone who contributed.

Comment: In `ls | cat` you make `cat` read from `stdin` (`stdout` from `ls`) and print to `stdout`. `txtfile` is likely the only think you'll see in the output, since that's the only file `ls` will list. `ls -> stdout|stdin -> cat -> stdout`

Comment: Maybe this illustration might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)#/media/File:Pipeline.svg

Comment: Or this article + illustration: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-spunix_pipeviewer/index.html

Comment: It does not become arguments, it becomes "keyboard input" on the other end. I.e. if you try to "read from the keyboard" you will instead get the output from the LHS. (Keyboards are not involved, it's just what CS101 teachers call it to avoid having to explain the inheritance of file descriptors up front)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you meant while performing

```
ls | cat
```

`ls` should return `txtfile` and which should go as a file input to `cat` command.

But, the things happening in the background are different :

1. First your shell creates a pipe using `pipe(int pipefd[2])` system-call. This pipe has 2 ends, one is read and another is write.
2. When `ls` command is executing, it writes its output to the write end of the pipe and `cat` simultaneously reads from the read end of the pipe.

So, here STDOUT of ls is the write end whereas STDIN for cat is read end of the pipe.

While reading from the pipe `cat` will consider it as a stream of bytes and not as a name of the file.

So basically, `cat` is printing whatever is coming as a stream of bytes.

Read about `pipe()` over here : [pipe(2) — Linux manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | cut -c 2-4
```

Here, `cut` reads its standard input, gets the line `txtfile`, takes characters 2 to 4 from it, producing `xtf`, and prints that on standard output. That's what the  command line option tells it to do.

```
ls | cat
```

Here, `cat` reads its standard input, gets the line `txtfile`, and prints that on standard output, unchanged. That's what `cat` does. If there were further lines, it would do the same for those.

---

Both read standard input unless one or more file names are given as arguments. That standard input is connected to the terminal (the same one where you enter the command line), unless you use pipes or redirections to change that.

So, run the command `cut -c 2-4`, and enter the line `abcdefghijkl`, and it will print out `bcd`. Because without any arguments, it reads its standard input, which is the terminal, by default. Similarly for running just `cat`, you'll get back the same line you entered.

Running `ls | cut -c 2-4` changes where the standard input comes from, but it doesn't create any new command line arguments (other than the `-c` and `2-4` you gave). Command line arguments are not the same as the standard input.

So, `echo txtfile | cat` is not the same as running `cat txtfile`, any more than running `echo txtfile | cut -c 2-4` is the same as running `cut -c 2-4 txtfile`. For some reason, you seem to expect the pipe should work differently for `cat` than it does for `cut`.